# How to move the dotted lines while I copy in MS excel 2013

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-office-2013

While I copy some cells in MS Excel 2013, the dotted line appears around the copied cells(widely known as the "**marching ants**"), but they're static. Lines don't move. In other words, the ants stopped "marching" and remain immobile. How can I keep it moving?

Comment: Could be just a screen rendering issue. Why do you need them to move?

Comment: I like it. I, in fact do not get any animated graphics in my MS Office application.

Answer (score 0):

You may have animations disabled. Go to **Control Panel > Ease of Access Center > Use the computer without a display**. Here you can tick to "**Turn off all unnecessary animations**"

Or you may have a registry setting called `DisableAnimations` under

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\Graphics`

If it exists, set it to 0 to enable animations again.

Comment: It's there. Already set to zero. Any other suggestions?

Comment: have a look around the internet for disabling animations. There are many, many, many hits for that. Then try the exact opposite of what is suggested. Toggle hardware acceleration for example in the various dialogs and settings.